# Real Data Type Mapping in H2 in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, spring-boot, h2

I have this table defined in H2

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_book_event (
    id              bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    rssi            real);
```

my POJO:

```
private Float rssi;
```

This line of code in my repository class

```
bookEvent.setRssi           ((Float)row.get("RSSI"));
```

Tue query comes from  `jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql)`

But I got this error running a Junit

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Float..
```

from the H2 doc. about REAL

> A single precision floating point number. Should not be used to
>   represent currency values, because of rounding problems.
>
> Mapped to java.lang.Float.

Comment: I think this is a java issue and has nothing to do with H2.

Comment: What is `row`? And how was it populated?

Comment: try using this `bookEvent.setRssi           ((Double)row.get("RSSI"));`

Comment: Apparently the value is stored as a `java.lang.Double` in that `row` thing - you need to check how that is done. The H2 JDBC driver does return that as as `java.lang.Float`